# Basic beginner's matrix class in Python

Tags: python, beginner, matrix

This is my first class. I've been working a while on it, some functions are future ideas and are right now just bare bones and intended to be worked on later. I'm really looking for a good review of what I have so far, I've never done this before so hopefully I'm off to a decent start. I tried to log my errors as well and handle them by skipping but annotating which values are trouble. Also first time using *args in my functions.

```
class Matrix():

    def __init__(self, height, width):
        self.rows = [[0]*width for i in range(height)]
        self.height = height
        self.width = width

    def __str__(self):
        s = "\n" + "\n".join([str(i) for i in [rows for rows in self.rows] ]) + "\n"
        return s

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f'{self.__class__.__name__} ({self.height!r} , {self.width!r})')

    def len(self):
        return self.height * self.width

    def __add__(self, matrix2):
        return

    def __mul__(self, matrix2):
        return

    def remove(self, item):
        return

    def fill_matrix(self, fill_list):
        index = 0
        for i in range(len(self.rows)):
            try:
                for j in range(len(self.rows[i])):
                    self.rows[i][j] = fill_list[index]
                    index += 1
            except IndexError:
                print (f"Matrix not filled \nMatrix fill stopped at: row {i}, Column {j}")
                break        
        return fill_list[index:]

    def add_value(self, *args):
        log = []
        for arg in args:
           try:
               arg_size = len(arg)
           except TypeError:
               log.append(f'Parameter must be sequence, skipped: {arg}')
               continue

           try:
               if arg_size == 3:
                       self.rows[arg[0]] [arg[1]] = arg[2]
               else:
                   log.append(f'Parameter has too little or too much data, skipped: {arg}')
           except  IndexError:
               log.append(f'Location parameters are out of range, skipped: {arg}')              
           except TypeError:
               log.append(f'Location indicies must contain integral types, skipped: {arg}')

        return log

myMat = Matrix(5,5)
overflow = myMat.fill_matrix([i for i in range(26)])

print(myMat)

Errors =  myMat.add_value((-1,3,500), (0,0,3),(51,5, 7), (1, 2, 667), [3,4,676], (1), (1,"a", 1), (1,1, "£"))
print(myMat)
```

Comment: I know no one has really said anything about it, but I'm generalizing my fill function to fill partitions or whole thing

Comment: Is there any reason not to use NumPy instead of writing your own class?

Comment: @Georgy, yes, I'm trying to write this Matrix Object to increase my understanding of how to think in an Object Oriented manner and to see if my solution and approach so far is a good start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. There is no need for brackets in `class Matrix(): ...`. It can be just `class Matrix: ...`. See [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#class-definition-syntax) for class definition syntax.
2. In `self.rows = [[0]*width for i in range(height)]` you should replace `i` by `_` that we usually use for [throwaway variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5893163/what-is-the-purpose-of-the-single-underscore-variable-in-python).
3. In the same line `0` is a [magic number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad). You could make it a default parameter:

   ```
   def __init__(self, height, width, fill_value=0):
       self.rows = [[fill_value] * width for _ in range(height)]
   ```

---

4. Regarding `__str__`:

   > ```
   > def __str__(self):
   >     s = "\n" + "\n".join([str(i) for i in [rows for rows in self.rows] ]) + "\n"
   >     return s
   > ```

   Having those `"\n"` on both ends seems unnecessary. Just return the middle part and let user decide if he wants more blank lines between output.
5. `[rows for rows in self.rows]` is the same as `self.rows`. That leaves us:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       s = "\n".join([str(i) for i in self.rows])
       return s
   ```
6. `i` is a bad name. `row` is better.
7. Removing unnecessary `s`:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return "\n".join([str(row) for row in self.rows])
   ```
8. And making it more concise:

   ```
   def __str__(self):
       return "\n".join(map(str, self.rows))
   ```

---

9. Regarding `__repr__`:

   > ```
   > def __repr__(self):
   >     return (f'{self.__class__.__name__} ({self.height!r} , {self.width!r})')
   > ```

   The brackets are unnecessary here, and spacing is a bit weird. It should be like this:

   ```
   return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.height!r}, {self.width!r})'
   ```
10. As you probably already know, with [`__repr__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1984162/purpose-of-pythons-repr) you should be able to pass the returned string to Python interpreter so that it could recreate the object. But in your case information about the values in your matrix would be lost. What you return is just something like `Matrix(5, 5)`. Would this be OK? Probably it would be better if the values would be returned as well, but then the current logic of the class won't allow you to recreate the matrix as you separated filling (`fill_matrix`) from initializing. Maybe it would be better to be able to do both at the same time?

---

11. `len` method should be called `__len__`.
12. As with current implementation its value is constant, you could use [`lru_cache(1)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.lru_cache) so to calculate it only once and then reuse the cached value:

    ```
    from functools import lru_cache

    ...

    @lru_cache(1)
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.height * self.width
    ```
13. You have some not implemented yet methods. Instead of returning nothing:

    > ```
    > def __add__(self, matrix2):
    >     return
    > ```

    raise a [`NotImplementedError`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#NotImplementedError):

    ```
    def __add__(self, matrix2):
        raise NotImplementedError
    ```

---

14. Regarding `fill_matrix`:

    > ```
    > def fill_matrix(self, fill_list):
    >     index = 0
    >     for i in range(len(self.rows)):
    >         try:
    >             for j in range(len(self.rows[i])):
    >                 self.rows[i][j] = fill_list[index]
    >                 index += 1
    >         except IndexError:
    >             print (f"Matrix not filled \nMatrix fill stopped at: row {i}, Column {j}")
    >             break        
    >     return fill_list[index:]
    > ```

    Add a docstring. It is not clear at the first sight why this method should return anything. Something like:

    ```
    def fill_matrix(self, fill_list):
        """
        Fills matrix by `fill_list`
        and returns what didn't fit in it.
        """
    ```
15. You are catching `IndexError` but this case seems impossible as indices are always taken from the ranges defined by shape of the matrix. You can remove it.
16. Why recalculating `len(self.rows)` and `len(self.rows[i])` if you already have `self.height` and `self.width`?
17. The idea of iterating the `index` doesn't seem Pythonic. How about something like this instead:

    ```
    from itertools import product

    ...

    def fill_matrix(self, fill_list):
        fill_values = iter(fill_list)

        indices = product(range(self.height), range(self.width))

        for (i, j), value in zip(indices, fill_values):
            self.rows[i][j] = value

        return fill_values
    ```

    This can accept iterators or sequences and will return an iterator with "overflow". So if you need to use those leftovers, you get them like this:

    ```
    myMat = Matrix(5, 5)
    overflow = myMat.fill(range(30))
    print(list(overflow))
    >>> [25, 26, 27, 28, 29]
    ```
18. It would be better to rename `fill_matrix` as `fill` and its argument `fill_list` as `values`.

---

19. Regarding `add_value`. I think it's better to name it `replace` instead.
20. This method is too complicated and doesn't follow [Single responsibility principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Catch the errors outside, and use this method just for replacing one value. If you need to replace multiple values, then put the function call inside the loop. See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30759501/loop-inside-or-outside-a-function) for a better explanation. In the end it should be as simple as that:

    ```
    def insert(self, row_index, column_index, value):
        self.rows[row_index][column_index] = value
    ```

    And you could call it, and catch and save the errors like this:

    ```
    import traceback

    ...

    values = [(-1, 3, 500),
              (0, 0, 3),
              (51, 5, 7),
              (1, 2, 667),
              [3, 4, 676],
              (1),
              [3, 4, 676, 123],
              (1, "a", 1),
              (1, 1, "£")]

    errors = []
    bad_values = []

    for value in values:
        try:
            myMat.insert(*value)
        except (IndexError, TypeError):
            errors.append(traceback.format_exc())
            bad_values.append(value)

    for error, value in zip(errors, bad_values):
        print(f'Error occurred for value {value}:\n'
              f'{error}')
    ```

    And the output is:

    ```
    Error occurred for value (51, 5, 7):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 82, in <module>
        myMat.insert(*value)
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 55, in insert
        self.rows[row_index][column_index] = value
    IndexError: list index out of range

    Error occurred for value 1:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 82, in <module>
        myMat.insert(*value)
    TypeError: insert() argument after * must be an iterable, not int

    Error occurred for value [3, 4, 676, 123]:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 82, in <module>
        myMat.insert(*value)
    TypeError: insert() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

    Error occurred for value (1, 'a', 1):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 82, in <module>
        myMat.insert(*value)
      File "C:/Users/Georgy/SO_CR/main.py", line 55, in insert
        self.rows[row_index][column_index] = value
    TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
    ```

    You might be interested in Python [logging module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html) as well.
    Though, I find it strange that you decided to pay so much attention to catching the errors.

---

Some other notes:

- Don't forget about naming conventions. `myMat` should be `my_matrix`, `Errors` should be `errors`. See [PEP 8:](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) for more.
- Consider using [type hints](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html).

---

In the end your code could look like this:

```
from functools import lru_cache
from itertools import product
from typing import (Any,
                    Iterable,
                    Iterator)


class Matrix:
    def __init__(self,
                 height: int,
                 width: int,
                 fill_value: Any = 0) -> None:
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
        self.rows = [[fill_value] * width for _ in range(height)]

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return "\n".join(map(str, self.rows))

    def __repr__(self) -> str:
        return f'{self.__class__.__name__}({self.height!r}, {self.width!r})'

    @lru_cache(1)
    def __len__(self) -> int:
        return self.height * self.width

    def __add__(self, matrix2):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def __mul__(self, matrix2):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def remove(self, item):
        raise NotImplementedError

    def fill(self, values: Iterable[Any]) -> Iterator[Any]:
        """
        Fills matrix by `fill_values`
        and returns what didn't fit in it.
        """
        values = iter(values)

        indices = product(range(self.height), range(self.width))

        for (i, j), value in zip(indices, values):
            self.rows[i][j] = value

        return values

    def replace(self,
                row_index: int,
                column_index: int,
                value: Any) -> None:
        """Replaces a value by given indices by a new one."""
        self.rows[row_index][column_index] = value
```